# MongoDB Capped Collections for logging

Tags: mongodb

I am reviewing how to store the LOG of service apps to MongoDB. I have found “Capped Collections” and “TTL”, and eventually I thought “Capped Collections” was suitable.

But there is a problem.

“Capped Collections” overwrites when the specified size is exceeded. But we can not, and we can not predict the size.

If reach the specified size, do not have a rollover function?

If not, In my case, should I find a solution that is not MongoDB?

Comment: Then it would be a TTL index which removes documents after defined time or at a certain point of time. Otherwise go for manual cleanup/rollover.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Will it be a LOGING to use INDEX? I think there is a performance problem. Do actually use TTL in Logging?

Comment: Not clear what you mean.